# Can't install lxml with Python3.5, Windows 10, 32 bit

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, lxml

Python 3.5 on Windows 10, 32-bit box; all I want to do is run this:

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
import lxml

# retrieve web page with list of 50 states
fiddy_states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.or      /wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```

But for the life of me I can't seem to get a properly installed lxml, which is required by `pd.read_html`. Following advice from several online sources I have MinGW installed in my system and I have also added the following to `C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg`:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

I have MinGW installed and included in `PATH`. I have tried installing lxml using both pip3 as well as the binaries found at [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

Here's all installed packages:

```
['beautifulsoup4==4.4.1', 'cffi==1.6.0', 'cryptography==1.3.2',   'cycler==0.10.0', 'cython==0.24', 'html5lib==0.9999999', 'idna==2.1', 'inflection==0.3.1', 'lxml==3.4.4', 'matplotlib==1.5.1', 'more-itertools==2.2', 'ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0', 'numpy==1.11.0', 'pandas-datareader==0.2.1', 'pandas==0.18.1', 'pip==8.1.2', 'pyasn1==0.1.9', 'pycparser==2.14', 'pyopenssl==16.0.0', 'pyparsing==2.1.4', 'python-dateutil==2.5.3', 'pytz==2016.4', 'quandl==3.0.1', 'requests-file==1.4', 'requests==2.10.0', 'scikit-learn==0.17.1', 'setuptools==18.2', 'six==1.10.0']
```

As shown above, `lxml==3.4.4` appears to be installed, however when I try to run the line containing  `pd.read_html` I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Jose Manuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32   \lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 874, in read_html
parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, attrs, encoding)
File "C:\Users\Jose Manuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 726, in _parse
parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
File "C:\Users\Jose Manuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 685, in _parser_dispatch
raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install itenter code here
```

Your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this today.  I found, elsewhere on stackoverflow.com, this two-part and quick solution, which resulted in python no longer complaining when I tried to use lxml:

1. go to [this repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and download a version which matches your Python installation (the version number, and 32- vs 64-bit.  I use Python 3.5.1 64-bit, installed on Windows 10, so on that page, I chose **lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**.  You say you have 32-bit Python, so use a version that matches that (like **lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl**.

My download directory is d:\Downloads.  Python must be in your PATH environment variable for the next step to work.  Use a command like the following, changing "D:\Downloads" to the pathname to your download directory.  Then, at a DOS prompt, type:

2. **python -m pip install "D:\Downloads\lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**

Comment: This worked but the weird thing is, while I'm running on a 64bit Windows 10 machine ... only the 32bit version of the wheel installed correctly.  Any ideas as to why?